# What are the actual limitations building a AMP only website?

Tags: amp-html

Building an AMP only website seems to be a good idea. But what are the actual limitations people are going to face by building a AMP only website?

Answer (score 2):

For understanding some limitations I recommend you to go through the following links.

- [AMP Medium 
  Article](https://medium.com/the-set-list/google-amp-a-70-drop-in-our-conversion-rate-35fe3cb69c59)
- [Going AMP](https://moz.com/blog/amp-digital-marketing-2018)
- [Pros & Cons
  SearchEngineJournal](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/do-i-need-amp/181292/)
- [Pros & Cons
  TheLeverageWay](https://www.theleverageway.com/blog/the-pros-and-cons-of-accelerated-mobile-pages-amps/)
- [Discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17717241)

Now whether it is a good idea or not depends heavily on the nature of your project. I think a more relevant question would be

> 'What are the benefits of using AMP for your project?'

Answer (score 0):

I want to change my website end of the year to mobile only with AMP.
My biggest problem are that Google analytics and tagmanager are not fully supported.
On a marketing site this is are problem that we will miss many things.

Comment: I'm having a similar conversation with a client right now about taking the blog section of their site to AMP only. I'm curious what you concluded here and how it went for you.

Comment: I guess you don't need to convert all of your pages to AMP. You just need to convert your heavy content pages (for example if you're an ad agency, you don't need to turn your about page or contact page into AMP), blog, news, videos, and anything else with good and searchable content can be converted to AMP, and you can have a link to your website at the bottom of the page or so. Also, you can use Google Analytics, the basic data like session duration, online users, and a few others are also available in AMP